# Replace row names with the column value of another data frame based on column matches

Tags: r

I want to replace the row names of `meth.kirp.cpg` with `anno$V1` if the existing row names matches `anno$V2`.

```
library(tidyverse)

rownames(meth.kirp.cpg) <- meth.kirp.cpg %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(out = anno$V1[str_which(colnames(meth.kirp.cpg), anno$V2)])
```

Traceback:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `out = anno$V1[str_which(rownames(meth.kirp.cpg),
  anno$V2)]`.
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error in `str_detect()`:
! Can't recycle `string` (size 142513) to match `pattern` (size 365860).
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Example data:

`meth.kirp.cpg`

```
> dput(meth.kirp.cpg[1:100,1:2])
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A = c(0.461440642939772, 0.143910373119058, 
0.847164847154162, 0.737361955793681, 0.716794733144112, 0.351877113536983, 
0.248986769373366, 0.0121360989202765, 0.876303885229884, 0.944311384947134, 
0.0490407302658151, 0.0200484962577958, 0.0623434271852525, 0.489865398138095, 
0.920994933496615, 0.92663932531651, 0.0149191766670711, 0.884749685210921, 
0.446591784140497, 0.91113228700911, 0.912199953863369, 0.908167409366654, 
0.386721526377863, 0.0386737340626713, 0.0347492896507038, 0.98309370597552, 
0.0176080612232509, 0.91878387167279, 0.743683318738873, 0.939148492241393, 
0.722471943330892, 0.613143449419421, 0.0111202783577944, 0.843823786705695, 
0.836431557867031, 0.390282953982417, 0.027408710286304, 0.0222349236137297, 
0.657221610108816, 0.861848830221141, 0.0433751011272091, 0.0281247935879252, 
0.938960776959358, 0.919825831744144, 0.922071582222369, 0.874732275907705, 
0.0287898761495033, 0.0266947996996682, 0.922915821025777, 0.95009866012662, 
0.964858875373814, 0.106451342824246, 0.406100902807456, 0.0421684244823044, 
0.0341277368595181, 0.805451068725895, 0.147595746750675, 0.602617067494429, 
0.90660866745333, 0.922313274809095, 0.462291286891102, 0.502857899902497, 
0.0292904155423265, 0.835117565787527, 0.146789494933407, 0.06805696389495, 
0.970563583145203, 0.0379479981289824, 0.058526761439653, 0.938993650169269, 
0.44761099556807, 0.558961729061086, 0.939778576056268, 0.0728795533192928, 
0.812084345787681, 0.899377654465699, 0.940111049552295, 0.838186810388758, 
0.715121288990262, 0.897506380407565, 0.0929678061732199, 0.99024632582796, 
0.055583745670494, 0.835146654988372, 0.973309086845447, 0.651216797099359, 
0.0218535991986461, 0.0999671036378156, 0.790540668893094, 0.980591855409854, 
0.567883806155822, 0.774816434396113, 0.904434807209845, 0.16641097147085, 
0.0102686285230525, 0.65243489007093, 0.917594420539083, 0.0147831247626457, 
0.844679485594683, 0.65566679452182), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A = c(0.595894468074615, 
0.0807243779293262, 0.867305510246114, 0.70680600651273, 0.217862460492399, 
0.169408257004071, 0.173115013795265, 0.0108902025634162, 0.813866558997356, 
0.938576461648791, 0.0426568318037534, 0.0133187057875756, 0.0540543120983417, 
0.317547629906197, 0.89911570032979, 0.525131175543627, 0.0152198596492253, 
0.586968687135673, 0.49896100615873, 0.946718072906056, 0.859306039060091, 
0.91185524112895, 0.28077646371254, 0.0413484993379312, 0.169193526857136, 
0.941230054689418, 0.0164701153466769, 0.928402415411224, 0.736184540407898, 
0.946288965623826, 0.312150292032857, 0.403171876971832, 0.0091246246912222, 
0.535149883791691, 0.801041308364712, 0.171664264695538, 0.022737572168221, 
0.0164834707992085, 0.34399568227201, 0.690016503202975, 0.0390842331750004, 
0.0270854886242561, 0.888936631403145, 0.911902815624012, 0.858247513475469, 
0.877113632682254, 0.0342892379505875, 0.0387268488822914, 0.922299785913074, 
0.926130065834329, 0.975692332236198, 0.105415153493416, 0.127593519059119, 
0.0540003798276299, 0.030980833881057, 0.914299941557146, 0.0512267439881511, 
0.307325891435045, 0.941037265659174, 0.927078967007025, 0.48873418258592, 
0.259006924115841, 0.0278764868641079, 0.87768067729952, 0.302640875302654, 
0.0706384569300761, 0.968762634771395, 0.0364352674378962, 0.0441231506131831, 
0.8307385629478, 0.242575477196221, 0.513439830376976, 0.932449172188782, 
0.0526229004254996, 0.81314353054328, 0.778591104943176, 0.95668645045373, 
0.453172059602829, 0.250129171963381, 0.863470213940097, 0.0994627135023581, 
0.989489689575077, 0.0472116225581592, 0.911407225108748, 0.825189076107663, 
0.578029414148402, 0.018058167343065, 0.0855852777154159, 0.819733395638372, 
0.988287891473147, 0.255899615791521, 0.643359326354994, 0.491979154678761, 
0.0978562004864199, 0.0105671614378101, 0.48897100984416, 0.9024550858788, 
0.0131702158217202, 0.81328537816321, 0.85890307119103)), row.names = c("cg00000029", 
"cg00000165", "cg00000236", "cg00000289", "cg00000292", "cg00000321", 
"cg00000363", "cg00000622", "cg00000658", "cg00000721", "cg00000734", 
"cg00000769", "cg00000905", "cg00000924", "cg00000948", "cg00000957", 
"cg00001245", "cg00001249", "cg00001261", "cg00001349", "cg00001364", 
"cg00001446", "cg00001510", "cg00001582", "cg00001583", "cg00001687", 
"cg00001747", "cg00001791", "cg00001809", "cg00001854", "cg00001874", 
"cg00002033", "cg00002116", "cg00002145", "cg00002190", "cg00002224", 
"cg00002236", "cg00002406", "cg00002426", "cg00002449", "cg00002464", 
"cg00002490", "cg00002531", "cg00002591", "cg00002593", "cg00002597", 
"cg00002660", "cg00002719", "cg00002769", "cg00002808", "cg00002809", 
"cg00002810", "cg00002837", "cg00003091", "cg00003173", "cg00003181", 
"cg00003287", "cg00003345", "cg00003513", "cg00003529", "cg00003578", 
"cg00003625", "cg00003784", "cg00003969", "cg00003994", "cg00004055", 
"cg00004067", "cg00004072", "cg00004082", "cg00004089", "cg00004105", 
"cg00004121", "cg00004192", "cg00004207", "cg00004209", "cg00004429", 
"cg00004533", "cg00004562", "cg00004608", "cg00004773", "cg00004818", 
"cg00004883", "cg00004939", "cg00004963", "cg00004979", "cg00004996", 
"cg00005010", "cg00005040", "cg00005072", "cg00005083", "cg00005112", 
"cg00005166", "cg00005215", "cg00005297", "cg00005306", "cg00005390", 
"cg00005437", "cg00005543", "cg00005617", "cg00005619"), class = "data.frame")
```

`anno`

```
> dput(anno[1:100,])
structure(list(V1 = c("TSPY4", "TTTY14", "TMSB4Y", "TBL1Y", "TMSB4Y", 
"TSPY4", "RPS4Y2", "EIF1AY", "PCDH11Y", "TBL1Y", "ZFY", "FAM197Y2", 
"TTTY14", "TSPY4", "ZFY", "NLGN4Y", "EIF1AY", "TSPY4", "TBL1Y", 
"UTY", "PRKY", "ZFY", "CD24", "PRKY", "TSPY1", "CYorf15A", "TSPY2", 
"TTTY15", "RPS4Y2", "UTY", "CYorf15A", "RPS4Y2", "TSPY2", "TBL1Y", 
"TSPY3", "DDX3Y", "CYorf15A", "ZFY", "RBMY1F", "DDX3Y", "RPS4Y2", 
"ZFY", "DDX3Y", "TTTY15", "BCORL2", "PCDH11Y", "KDM5D", "TTTY14", 
"EIF1AY", "DDX3Y", "LOC100101121", "CYorf15A", "TTTY15", "TSPY1", 
"TSPY1", "FAM197Y2", "TSPY4", "TMSB4Y", "DDX3Y", "TTTY15", "TTTY20", 
"NLGN4Y", "TSPY4", "CYorf15A", "RPS4Y2", "KDM5D", "RBMY1J", "EIF1AY", 
"KDM5D", "ZFY", "TGIF2LY", "HMGN5", "EBP", "UBL4A", "WDR13", 
"MTM1", "BCOR", "ZCCHC12", "FTHL17", "PORCN", "NAA10", "PCDH11X", 
"ARSE", "DOCK11", "PDK3", "LONRF3", "MAGIX", "PCYT1B", "SLC6A8", 
"UBE2A", "TAF9B", "STARD8", "BCOR", "ZIC3", "IL1RAPL2", "TMSB4X", 
"CLCN5", "LOC100133957", "SCML1", "GNL3L"), V2 = c("cg00050873", 
"cg00212031", "cg00214611", "cg01707559", "cg02004872", "cg02011394", 
"cg02050847", "cg02233190", "cg02494853", "cg02839557", "cg02842889", 
"cg03052502", "cg03244189", "cg03443143", "cg03683899", "cg03706273", 
"cg03750315", "cg04016144", "cg04042030", "cg04448376", "cg04689676", 
"cg04840163", "cg05230942", "cg05480730", "cg05544622", "cg05621349", 
"cg05865243", "cg05890011", "cg06322277", "cg06479204", "cg07731488", 
"cg07747963", "cg08242338", "cg08921682", "cg09350919", "cg09856092", 
"cg10076560", "cg10213302", "cg10267609", "cg10698069", "cg10841270", 
"cg11131351", "cg14180491", "cg14741114", "cg15027426", "cg15295597", 
"cg15329860", "cg15345074", "cg15422579", "cg15429127", "cg15682806", 
"cg15682993", "cg15746461", "cg15810474", "cg15935877", "cg17834650", 
"cg17837162", "cg18032798", "cg18077436", "cg25032547", "cg25071634", 
"cg25518695", "cg25705492", "cg25756647", "cg26058907", "cg26517491", 
"cg26983430", "cg26983535", "cg27049643", "cg27433982", "cg27539833", 
"cg00008945", "cg00011200", "cg00011891", "cg00014152", "cg00016522", 
"cg00016934", "cg00018261", "cg00021786", "cg00026186", "cg00072288", 
"cg00072839", "cg00074638", "cg00112256", "cg00114625", "cg00114913", 
"cg00116709", "cg00139317", "cg00140085", "cg00142683", "cg00192980", 
"cg00200463", "cg00206414", "cg00240113", "cg00241296", "cg00241907", 
"cg00264378", "cg00265812", "cg00266918", "cg00360365")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
20L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 47L, 48L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 54L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 61L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 82L, 83L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 91L, 
92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 
104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 
115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Mind that the new rownames (by whichever method obtained) must still be unique.

Answer (score 0):

There is no match between your cpg dataframe and annotation dataframe:

```
table(rownames(meth.kirp.cpg) %in% anno$V2)
# FALSE 
#   100
```

Below should work with your full data, assuming there is are no duplicates and all rownames are in annotation dataframe:

```
rownames(meth.kirp.cpg) <- anno$V2[ match(rownames(meth.kirp.cpg), anno$V2) ]
```